# Attach unzipped files to wordpress

Tags: uploads

I tried to add a page template to upload zip files and extract on fly. i do it correctly except attaching extracted files to media files and post attachments only zip file attached.

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);

if (!function_exists('wp_generate_attachment_metadata')){
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
}

if ($_FILES) {
    foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
        if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            return "upload error : " . $_FILES[$file]['error'];
        }
        WP_Filesystem(); 
        $folder = wp_upload_dir();  
        $archive_files = unzip_file($_FILES['sfile']['tmp_name'], $folder['path'] );
        $attach_id = media_handle_upload($file, $post_id ); 
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id);
        $post_id =  wp_update_post( $post );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you unzipped the file to `$folder['path']` you have to manually add all unzipped files to the $_FILES array and do media_handle_upload, etc. for them. You are iterating over it, so you may create a temporary $unzippedfiles array and push all unzipped files into it.
You have to create for each file an entry similar to which it would appear in $_FILES. Especially the files should be put into the default php upload directory `ini_get('upload_tmp_dir')` so that the wordpress functions can handle it correctly.

After you have looped the entire $_FILES array once you may replace it with $unzippedfiles and iterate over it doing the attachement stuff.

Here is some code that should handle your problem:

```
    $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);

    if (!function_exists('wp_generate_attachment_metadata')){
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
    }
    function dir_tree($dir) {
        //http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.scandir.php#102505
        $paths = array();
        $stack[] = $dir;
        while ($stack) {
            $thisdir = array_pop($stack);
            if ($dircont = scandir($thisdir)) {
                $i=0;
                while (isset($dircont[$i])) {
                    if ($dircont[$i] !== '.' && $dircont[$i] !== '..') {
                        $current_file = "{$thisdir}/{$dircont[$i]}";
                        if (is_file($current_file)) {
                            $paths[] = "{$thisdir}/{$dircont[$i]}";
                        } elseif (is_dir($current_file)) {
                            $paths[] = "{$thisdir}/{$dircont[$i]}";
                            $stack[] = $current_file;
                        }
                    }
                    $i++;
                }
            }
        }
        return $paths;
    }

    if ($_FILES) {
        $unzipped = array();
        foreach ($_FILES as $fid => $array) {
            if ($array['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                return "upload error : " . $array['error'];
            }
            WP_Filesystem(); 

            $folder = ini_get('upload_tmp_dir')."/unzipped_".basename($array['tmp_name']);
            if( ! is_dir( $folder ) ) {
                mkdir( $folder );
            }

            if( unzip_file($array['tmp_name'], $folder ) === True ) {
                $filepaths = dir_tree( $folder );
                foreach( $filepaths as $k => $filepath ) {
                    if( is_file($filepath) ) {
                        $file = array();
                        $file['name'] = basename( $filepath );
                        $file['size'] = filesize( $filepath );
                        $file['tmp_name'] = $filepath;
                        $unzipped["unzipped_$k"] = $file;
                    }
                }
            }

            $attach_id = media_handle_upload($fid, $post_id );
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id);
            $post_id =  wp_update_post();
        }
        foreach ($unzipped as $file ) {
            $attach_id = media_handle_sideload($file,$post_id);
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id);
            $post_id =  wp_update_post();
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you please edit code to work. it is already extract zip file on the same upload directory and also attach zip file, but not attach extracted files.

Comment: i changed a few things. now it could work.

Comment: thanks for help, but your fix only attach zip, not extracting file at all.

Comment: can you tell me where you put this code, so i can debug it locally?

Comment: i am using as a page template. plz contact me at (ayman2it at gmail) to send you full page.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are over using the attachment feature,you are right about using the unzip_file and filesystem api, but regarding to the attachment itself I suggest to just add a normal post meta and store the attachment folder in it .

Comment: zip file already attached, but extracted files not. Any Update?